# Safari/Chrome (Webkit) - Cannot hide iframe vertical scrollbar

Tags: css, iframe, safari, webkit, scrollbar

I have an `iframe` on www.example.com that points to support.example.com (which is a CNAME to a foreign domain).

I automatically resize the height of my iframe so that the frame will not need any scrollbars to display the contained webpage.

On Firefox and IE this works great, there is no scrollbar since I use `<iframe ... scrolling="no"></iframe>`. However, on webkit browsers (Safari and Chrome), the vertical scrollbar persists even when there is sufficient room for the page without the scrollbar (the scrollbar is grayed out).

How do I hide the scrollbar for webkit browsers?

Comment: Note for posterity: this was a bug in webkit browsers that has since been fixed. Here's the bug report: https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=29240

Comment: why didn't you accept any!?

Answer (score 66):

I just ran into this problem, and discovered that the fix was to set `overflow: hidden` on the HTML tag of the page inside the `iframe`.

Comment: Thanks for this tip, Tim; it fixed the issue for me.

By the way, it seems like styling the HTML element to be overflow:hidden inside of a style tag doesn't work -- you need to put it in as a style attribute for the HTML tag (even though that's not valid). So...

This:
    <html style="overflow: hidden;">
    <head></head>
    <body>stuff</body>
    </html>

Not this:
    <html>
    <head><style type="text/css"> html { overflow:hidden; } </style></head>
    <body>stuff</body>
    </html>

Comment: In Chrome/10.0.648.133 it seems to work whether the overflow:hidden is in the `<html>` tag, in an inline style, or even in an external stylesheet — although Chrome seems to be a little too aggressive about caching external stylesheets. Maybe this bug was fixed sometime over the years.

Comment: Does it make a difference if I add `overflow:hidden;` to the `body` tag instead of `html`?

Answer (score 53):

You can hide the scrollbars and maintain the scrolling functionality (by touchpad or scroll wheel, or touch and drag in a mobile phone or tablet, by using:

```
<style>
  iframe::-webkit-scrollbar {  
    display: none;
  }  
</style>
```

Obviously, you can change iframe to whatever fits your design, and you can add the equivalent -mozilla- property to get it work in firefox as well.

Comment: Isn't there a moderator who can make this the correct answer?

Comment: @Hendrik it is up to the user that opened the question to choose a correct answer.

Comment: Thanks @palako. Just a note, if you want to maintain the vertical scroll visible, just use: iframe::-webkit-scrollbar:horizontal {display: none;} to only hide the horizontal.

Comment: You can flag the incorrect answer as "not an answer" - because it's not.

Comment: This CSS seems to not work in newest Chrome, you have to do that in the iframe itself.

Comment: @neatcoding, it's not working for me as well. Chrome 71 on mac.

Answer (score 17):

```
Note: this is useful if you cannot edit the CSS / HTML of the iFramed content.
```

It's a bit of a hack, but I solved this issue by wrapping the `<iframe>` in a `<div>`, setting the `<div>`'s height, width & `overflow:hidden`, then setting the `<iframe>`'s width & height to actually overflow the wrapping `<div>`.

```
<style>
  div {height:100px;width:100px;overflow:hidden}
  iframe {height:150px;width:150px;overflow:hidden}
</style>

<div>
  <iframe src="foo.html" scrolling="no"></iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: That's a brute-force approach that should work as a workaround to missing features or bugs :)

Comment: just adding overflow:hidden to the iframe style was enough to get the scrolling setting working for me in Safari, chrome and IE

Answer (score 11):

I'm assuming you've tried this, but have you set scrolling to no on the iframe?

```
<iframe scrolling="no">
```

Comment: yup. I didn't escape that flag in my post, unfortunately, so it didn't display.

Answer (score 6):

To get rid of the greyed out scroll bars, put "overflow: hidden;" on the body tag of the page being displayed in the Iframe e.g. `<body style="overflow:hidden;">` This worked fine for me in Chrome 8.0.552.215 and I also had "overflow: hidden" on the Iframe itself

Answer (score 3):

Does this help? Works on Chrome, IE, FF...

```
<style type="text/css">
html { overflow:hidden; }
#test { position:absolute; top:50; left:50; right:50; bottom:50; height:2000px; }
</style>

<body scroll="no">
<div id="test">content</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2):

Can you set the `overflow-y` CSS property for the IFRAME to either `visible` or `hidden`?

Comment: Setting the overflow-y css property to hidden directly for the IFRAME, or for the html/body tags of the contained web page seems to have no effect. Could I be overriding this property somehow?

Comment: -1 `overflow-y` is not a standard CSS property; it is IE only.

Answer (score 2):

check if the scroll is realy from the iframe, maybe it's from the HTML or BODY.

For scroll in iframe

```
<iframe scrolling="no">
```

In css

```
iframe { overflow:hidden; }

or 

iframe { overflow-x:hidden; overflow-y:hidden}
```

Answer (score 2):

I just solved it on my blog with scrolling="no" after the style tag.

eg:

```
iframe src="asdf.html" style="overflow: hidden;" scrolling="no"
```

I left the style attribute in there because it's more proper and it worked fine on Firefox.

Answer (score 2):

Using Chrome 8.0.552.224 beta under Ubuntu 10.10 is showing still the ghost scrollbars on this site: http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_iframe_scrolling. I tried all tricks what works in all browsers but not in WebKit based browser. Therefore the bug seems not to be fixed completely.

Answer (score 2):

```
document.body.addEventListener('touchmove', function(e){ e.preventDefault(); });
```

this works, none of the others seemed to work including the `e.preventDefault()` for touchstart.

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

```
iframe { overflow:hidden; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Do not use scrolling tag at-all on the iframe and add the style as
style="overflow-x:hidden;overflow-y:auto;"
this will remove the horizontal scroll and it should work the other way round too.

Answer (score 1):

Setting the iframe's scrolling attribute to "no" *should* fix this, but there appears to be a bug in webkit: https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=29240

Tim's work-around ( [Safari/Chrome (Webkit) - Cannot hide iframe vertical scrollbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1691873/safari-chrome-webkit-cannot-hide-iframe-vertical-scrollbar/1848336#1848336) ) seems to fix the issue -- **as long as** you have the ability to edit the document contained by the iframe...

Answer (score 1):

hide iframe scrolling in chrome put body tag like this

```
<body style="margin:0px; padding:0px; overflow:hidden;"></body>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<iframe> <body style="overflow-x: hidden"> </body> </iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

1.when you change iframe's scrolling yes or no, the iframe's scrollbar dosen't show immediately, you must refresh the iframe.

2.the html tap overflow in iframe colud influence the iframe's scrollbar

3.in the IE,you must clear iframe's src,then refresh iframe ,it will be work

4.so, show you the code

html

```
<iframe id="main_ifrm" class="main"  frameborder="0" scrolling="no" src="new.html" ></iframe>
<button id="btn1">scrolling yes</button>
```

javascript

```
var ifrm = document.getElementById("main_ifrm");
var btn1 = document.getElementById("btn1");
btn1.onclick = function(){
    $(ifrm).prop("scrolling","no");
    $(ifrm.contentWindow.document).find("html").css("overflow","hidden")
    var src = $(ifrm).prop("src");
    $(ifrm).prop("src","");
    $(ifrm).prop("src",src);
}
```