# Remove vertical scroll bar, keep horizontal scroll bar in iframe in Chrome

Tags: iframe, google-chrome, scrollbar, overflow

I have an iframe for which I would like to enable a horizontal scroll bar, but disable the vertical scroll bar.

I have the iframe styled as such: `overflow-y:hidden; overflow-x:auto;`

This works just fine in FireFox, but not Chrome. Is there any sort of workaround to get this to work in Chrome?

**Update:**
I have transitioned into using a table cell with overflow, rather than an iframe. I don't know if this will make it easier or harder to work around that vertical scroll.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Safari/Chrome (Webkit) - Cannot hide iframe vertical scrollbar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1691873/safari-chrome-webkit-cannot-hide-iframe-vertical-scrollbar). Both tagged Chrome / webkit.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The answer is actually here:

[Safari/Chrome (Webkit) - Cannot hide iframe vertical scrollbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1691873/safari-chrome-webkit-cannot-hide-iframe-vertical-scrollbar/1848336#1848336)

Good luck!!

Answer (score 2):

This works well in any browser

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd"> 
<html> 
<head> 
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1"> 
<title>Untitled 1</title> 
</head> 
<style type="text/css"> 
#test iframe { 
width: 100%; 
height: 100%; 
border: none; } 

#test { 
width: 100%; 
height: 3530px; 
padding: 0; 
overflow: hidden; } 

</style> 

<body style="margin:0;"> 
<div id="test"> 
<iframe src="http://stackoverflow.com/" scrolling="no">
</iframe> 
</div> 
</body> 
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you cant find anything else:

Put the height of the iframe to =>103%

See here:

http://forums.aspfree.com/web-layout-43/horizontal-scrollbar-iframe-removing-23237-2.html

It is workaround that might just work...

You tell me!

Good luck

Comment: Thats a shame, I´ll look for something else and let you know!!

Answer (score 0):

Add parent div element to iframe like this:

```
<div style='overflow: hidden; width: 600px; height: 400px;'>
    <iframe src='http://www.website.com/index.html' style='overflow-y: hidden;' width='580' height='400' frameborder='0' seamless='seamless'></iframe>
</div>
```

It will hide vertical scroll bar but user could still use '**page up**', '**page down**' and **arrow keys** options for vertical scrolling.