# iframe scrollbars not showing in IE8

Tags: html, css, iframe

I have an IFrame on my page that I would like to show the vertical scroll bar ONLY (no horizontal scroll bar).  I can get it to work exactly how I want it in Firefox, but the scroll bars just will not show up in IE(8).

```
<iframe name="Frame" id="Frame" frameborder="0" scrolling="yes" marginwidth="0px" marginheight="0px" style="height:300px; width:1055px; overflow-x:hidden; margin-left:-30px"></iframe>
```

I tried putting the above into a div, and I finally get scrollbars, but since the IFrame itself isn't growing, they are never activated.

Are there any IE specific properties that I can use to get this to work on both browsers, or am I going at this the wrong way?

Thanks,
Jeff

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to set the height on the page that is being displayed in the iframe.

It was tricky due to the fact that the page is actually a sharepoint webpart with everything being created dynamically in VB

Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 1):

You're using `overflow-x` property in your style attribute, so it's removing the scroll bar (AFAIK).

Try setting `overflow-x` to `scroll`

Comment: I am using overflow-x:hidden because I don't want the horizontal bar (the content in the Iframe will never get wider - and it fits the current width)

Answer (score 1):

try to set the `overflow-y:scroll;` explicitly on the iframe, also, you probably need to set `overflow:hidden;` to the container (parent element) of the iframe, as per this other answer: [Safari/Chrome (Webkit) - Cannot hide iframe vertical scrollbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1691873/safari-chrome-webkit-cannot-hide-iframe-vertical-scrollbar).