# Full page (interstitial) ads with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, fullscreen, ads

I am trying to build a full page ad like those from Adbrite with jQuery.

It's simply an iframe with 100% width and height but my main problem is that the full page ad is shown in a website that has a vertical scrollbar, so if the iframe ad also has a scrollbar then two scrollbars are visible and it looks bad.

How could I solve that? or is there some already made code to do it?

Comment: This is already answered in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1691873/safari-chrome-webkit-cannot-hide-iframe-vertical-scrollbar

Comment: I don't want to hide the iframe scrollbar, if I am going to hide one in any case would be the one from the main page, if I hide the one in the iframe how is the user supposed to watch the entire advertised website?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding this at the top of the parent page or the equivalent in your css file if you're using one.

```
<STYLE TYPE="text/css"> 
<!-- 
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
body {overflow: hidden};
--> 
</STYLE>
```

The overflow:hidden should remove any scrollbars.

The other part should allow the iframe to use the full width/height of the browser.