# Why is my iFrame still showing scroll bars?

Tags: html, iframe

I have created an iframe within my site.  It loads when I click on another part of the site.  However I dont want it to show the scrollbars but they are showing even with the property set to no as shown in my code.  Does anyone have any ideas?

```
<iframe id="theFrame" src="" style="width:800px; height:450px; border:0px solid black; overflow:hidden;" scrolling="no"></iframe>
```

Comment: Is the iframe showing a 3rd party site or somewhere within your own site. If the latter have you tried using a user control instead

Comment: The iframe is showing another page in my solution - developing in Visual Studio 2010

Comment: could you not make the important information a user control and drop it on to the page?

Comment: @DanielCasserly - got it sorted - as one of the posters said below - the page I am opening in the iframe - I didnt have the overflow : auto changed it in.  I changed it in that page to overflow : hidden and it worked fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got this sorted - I was opening another page in my own solution in this iframe.

```
<style type="text/css">
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
}
body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
#silverlightControlHost {
    height: 100%;
    text-align:center;

}
</style>
```

I needed to change the overflow to hidden on this page and it worked fine.

Answer (score -1):

You could try adding `overflow:hidden;` to the style properties.

Comment: There is aleady `overflow:hidden;` in the style properties.

Comment: Oops, coffee needed. Sorry. There are some helpful posts here, though: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1691873/safari-chrome-webkit-cannot-hide-iframe-vertical-scrollbar

Comment: yes, should be: set overflow: hidden on the HTML tag of the page inside the iframe. But I think `style="width:800px; height:450px;"` forces to show the scroll.