# iframe scroll bar issue in chrome and IE

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc-4

I have an iframe for which we need to show only horizontal scroll bar and prevent vertical scroll bar.

```
<div class="restricted">
   <iframe runat="server" id="ifEmailBody" scrolling="auto" width="600" frameborder="1">   </iframe>
</div>


.restricted{overflow:hidden; overflow-y: hidden;}
.restricted iframe
{
   overflow:hidden; 
   overflow-y: hidden;
}
```

This is hiding vertical scroll bar in Fireforx. 
But it is not hiding it in Chrome and IE.

Can somebody advise how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

[Safari/Chrome (Webkit) - Cannot hide iframe vertical scrollbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1691873/safari-chrome-webkit-cannot-hide-iframe-vertical-scrollbar/1848336#1848336)

Hope you can find solution here

Comment: i added a link. hope it helps

Comment: I have already seen  that, however I am unable to set overflow:hidden to html tag inside iframe. Not able to access that in css