# How to hide scrolling bar from the iframed page

Tags: html, css

I have an iframe on HTML page, and I want to hide vertical "scrolling".

In my CSS, I input this, but I didn't get results, scrolling is still visible.

```
iframe{
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

Also, i try to use "style= scrolling="no"" but still withouts success.

Comment: you can find the answer here I think http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1691873/safari-chrome-webkit-cannot-hide-iframe-vertical-scrollbar/1848336#1848336

Comment: It didn't help me, i tryed :\

Comment: can you provide link or fiddle ?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/98zby3tf/

Answer (score 1):

`scrolling="no"` is an attribute, not a CSS property. It doesn't need to be wrapped in `style`:

```html
<iframe
  src="https://example.com/"
  width="100" height="100"
  scrolling="no"
>
</iframe>
```

Comment: <iframe src="http://google.com" frameborder="0" name= "myiframe" style="width:100%" height="1000px" width="100%"; overflow: hidden;"></iframe>   This is my code, i also tryed yours but it still display me vertical scroll.

Answer (score 1):

I fix the problem by adding position: fixed in css.

Comment: position: fixed of which element?

Comment: position:fixed :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `<iframe src="#" scrolling="no"></iframe>`.
Hope that helps!

Comment: @Serbon that does work with Chrome. I've tried it before.

Answer (score 0):

If iframe content is in same domain and
If you are ready to use JS to hide scroll inside iframe content, you can use this:

```
var elem = document.getElementById("if");
elem.contentDocument.body.style.overflow="hidden"
```

considering "if" as id of your iframe.

or use scrolling="no" as mentioned in another answer.